# Allow Customers to Add and Delete Products/Images/Categories from Frontend

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, frontend, permissions, products-management

In an existing magento store - I have been asked to integrate the ability for the stores trade clients to create products, categories and images themselves. In effect it would become a kind of portfolio or showcase needing the ability to:

- add new products and delete
- add new categories and delete
- add new images and delete

I know i can do all these things programmatically at times but my question is whether magento is built or can be adapted for this purpose safely?

By the sounds of it eventually the majority of the site would become this meaning everything for products, categories and images would all be controlled by the clients themselves not an admin

Is magento and the database structure built to handle all these actions being done on the front end? I worry that giving this amount of control could cause issues for the rest of the site and database tables?

Comment: You can use marketplace modules available in magento connect to fulfill this need. let me know if any more info is required on this.

Answer (score 2):

Magento is not really built for this and actually prevents modification of products and categories from the frontend as security measure. You can bypass this with `Mage::register('isSecureArea', true)` but I would be very careful doing that.

In the backend however, Magento has an extensive roles and permissions management system. The Magento way would be to give your trade clients admin accounts that are restricted to exactly the operations that you want to allow them. If you want to adjust the look and feel of the admin panel for your clients, you can implement a custom admin theme.

Answer (score 0):

You should use marketplace extension to do those tasks :

```
https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Marketplace.html

https://www.apptha.com/magento/marketplace
```

Go to these links and see the live demo

Cheers :)